# Sending data to nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest

I'm learning nodejs at the moment and I'm stuck with a few things.
I'm creating a server that's serving a html file. That html file has a js that does an xmlHttpRequest to get data. The data I'm retrieving I want to send back to my server to process it. And that last step is where I'm stuck. every time the server stops, while I would like to receive the urls in the server to process them.

**Server.js**

```
var http = require('http'),
    url = require('url'),
    path = require('path'),
    fs = require('fs');

var mimeTypes = {
    "html": "text/html",
    "js": "text/javascript",
    "css": "text/css"};

    http.createServer(function(request, response){

        var uri = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
        var filename = path.join(process.cwd(), uri);

        fs.exists(filename, function(exists){
            if(!exists){
                console.log(filename + " does not exist");
                response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'});
                response.write('404 Not found\n');
                response.end();
                return;
            }

            var mimeType = mimeTypes[path.extname().split(".")[1]];
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : mimeType});

            var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
            fileStream.pipe(response);
        });

    response.on('end', function(){
        console.log("Request: " + request);
        console.log("Response: " + response);
    });

    }).listen(1337);
```

**Client.js**

```
function getURLs(){
    var moduleURL = document.getElementById("url").value;
    var urls = [];
    console.log(moduleURL);

    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            var xml = xmlhttp.responseXML;
            var items = xml.children[0].children[0].children;

            for(var i = 13; i<items.length; i++){
                urls.push(items[i].children[1].getAttribute("url")+"&hd=yes");
            }

            //console.log(urls);
            sendDataToServer(urls);
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", moduleURL, true); 
    xmlhttp.send();

}

function sendDataToServer(urls){
    //console.log(urls);

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:1337/", true);
    http.send(urls);
}
```

I'm getting this in the console of the browser

> POST http://127.0.0.1:1337/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

And this in cmd of node

> events.js:72
>           throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>                 ^ Error: EISDIR, read

And while it's processing the data I would like to send back the progress to the client to show it on the html page for the end user. I already have the function of the progress it's only the sending/receiving of data where I am stuck. Can someone point me in the correct direction please?

I also know that there is express and other modules that I can use, but to learn node I'm trying it to do it this way. So I hope someone can push me in the correct direction.

Comment: It doesn't look like your server has a route that catches the ajax URL, whatever that is ?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more please?

Comment: When you're sending POST data to an URL the server has to catch it. You're sending it to `/`, and you have a server that catches everything, but it doesn't seem to do anything or return anything, maybe something more like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/5eeLn17o/**

Comment: @adeneo can you please post it as an answer so I can accept it? Because your snippet really helped me. Can you also push me in the correct direction with sending data back to my client(second part of my question)? While I'm processing the urls I'm doing a calculation to show the amount % processed and it's working and I just want to output it in my html.

Comment: That's a bit more complicated, with ajax you can really only return data once, and not while the request is ongoing. You'd probably have to do some sort of long polling to get the percentage back as it's sending it, or use websockets, with sockets you could send the percentage back to the browser while the ajax request was sending data.

Comment: Cool that answers my questions and now I know where to have a look at :)
Are you adding your snippet as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

> events.js:72 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event ^ Error: EISDIR, read

This error means that the file you're trying to read is actually a directory.

What you need to do is make sure that the file is really a file as the function *fs.exists()* is only for files.

In this example fs.lstat() is used to get a [fs.stat](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats) object which has the methods you need to make sure that a file is of the right type.

```
var http = require('http'),
url = require('url'),
path = require('path'),
fs = require('fs');

var mimeTypes = {
    "html": "text/html",
    "js": "text/javascript",
    "css": "text/css"
};

http.createServer(function(request, response){

    var uri = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    var filename = path.resolve(path.join(process.cwd(), uri));
    console.log(filename);

    // Get some information about the file
    fs.lstat(filename, function(err, stats) {

      // Handle errors
      if(err) {
        response.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'});
        response.write('Error while trying to get information about file\n');
        response.end();
        return false;
      }

      // Check if the file is a file.
      if (stats.isFile()) {

        fs.exists(filename, function(exists){
            if(!exists){
                console.log(filename + " does not exist");
                response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'});
                response.write('404 Not found\n');
                response.end();
                return;
            }

            var mimeType = mimeTypes[path.extname().split(".")[1]];
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : mimeType});

            var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
            fileStream.pipe(response);
        });

      } else {
        // Tell the user what is going on.
        response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'});
        response.write('Request url doesn\'t correspond to a file. \n');
        response.end();
      }

    });

response.on('end', function(){
    console.log("Request: " + request);
    console.log("Response: " + response);
});

}).listen(1337);
```

Comment: I also implemented your pieces of snippet but I'm getting Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://127.0.0.1:1337/css/style.css". and same for the js. What am I doing wrong? Because how I look at it, it seems fine??